# print everything in one line

Tags: php, css, html

Lets say that you have the following lines generated by a PHP framework:

```
ID: 1   
Name: David
LoginName: DavidAppple
Password: IamDavid  
Email: IamDavid@gmail.com
Phone: +555 333 222 111
```

say that you want to get these in 1 line, so it becomes:

```
ID: 1   Name: David LoginName: DavidAppple Password: IamDavid Email: IamDavid@gmail.com  Phone: +555 333 222
```

all in a single line how can you do that?

this is CSS CODE:

```
div.view
{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

<div class="items">

<div class="view">

    <b>ID:</b>
    <a href="/testdrive/index.php/user/1">1</a> <br />

    <b>Name:</b>
    David   <br />

    <b>LoginName:</b>
    DavidAppple <br />

    <b>Password:</b>
    IamDavid    <br />

    <b>Email:</b>
    IamDavid@gmail.com  <br />

    <b>Phone:</b>
    +555 333 222 111    <br />


</div></div>
```

this is the html part generated by PHP framwrok Yii, I want to be able to remove the `<br />` so I can have everything in 1 line.

Comment: It works. Please show the complete HTML markup. Is each line in own div, for example?

Comment: You should post the actual code of the view (with your php code you use to print the data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have break tags  `br` that are causing this.

Just hide them. Then the other items will re-assume their inline defaults.

```
div.view br {
    display: none;
}
```

```css
div.view {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
div.view br {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">

  <div class="view">

    <b>ID:</b>
    <a href="/testdrive/index.php/user/1">1</a> 
    <br />

    <b>Name:</b>
    David
    <br />

    <b>LoginName:</b>
    DavidAppple
    <br />

    <b>Password:</b>
    IamDavid
    <br />

    <b>Email:</b>
    IamDavid@gmail.com
    <br />

    <b>Phone:</b>
    +555 333 222 111
    <br />


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If every lines is wrapped by a `div.view` you can try:

```
div.view
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Css property indicates the span of float: left . Encapsulala within the div where encuente .

An example :

```css
span {float:left);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply str_replace() br tag with empty string if you have the produced string available to you in PHP. If not, just make sure br tags are set to display:none within the div.view.